# fixed width site to be responsive

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a fixed width layout I am trying to make responsive, I have looked at the code and `#wrapper` div isn't adjusting to full width when I use the different views in Dreamweaver.

The footer I get a scroll bar and the `footer`, `slider`, `top-bg` are all not going full width. But the content area does?

I changed the wrapper to 100% thinking that this would adjust everything within the page to move full screen but that hasn't worked?

### CSS:

```
/* Containers */

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
#top {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#top-bg {
    background-color:#03274B;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#topnav {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#topnav-bg {
    clear:both;
    background-color:#072C53;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px 0;
    border-top:2px #2B4D71 solid;
    border-bottom:2px #2B4D71 solid;
}
#banner-bg {
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(../images/bg/blue-bg.fw.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
#banner {
    padding:0px 0;
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#subbanner {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:30px 20px;
}
#subbanner-bg {
    width:100%;
}
#subbanner h1 {
    font-size:48px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
}
#content-wrap {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#leftside {
    width:425px;
    margin-right:50px;
    float:left;
}
#leftside h2 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
}
#rightside {
    width:425px;
    float:right;
}
#rightside h2 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
}
#content {
}
#content-bg {
}
#content-wrap {
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px 0;
}
#footer-bg {
    clear:both;
    background-color:#03274B;
    width:100%;
}
#footer p {
}
```

Comment: please do something about your code, it is very hard to look at...

Comment: I have fixed the question up as it was burning my eyes looking at it. Just waiting for someone to accept it.

Comment: sorry was my first time posting a post - not sure why it went bold!

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your HTML markup we have to make some assumptions. I also suggest you do not use the design views in Adobe Dreamweaver as they bear very little relation to how a browser will render your page, I suggest you press `F12` (Windows) or `option + F12` (Macintosh) to view your page in your preferred browser.

The CSS you posted appears a little broken, I am assuming that in areas such as `top {...}` you actually have `#top {...}` as `top` is a non-standard element.

That being said you still have areas in your CSS such as:

```
#top { 
   width:900px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

The element with `id="top"` will only ever be `900px` wide despite the size of it's parent element (possibly `id="wrapper"`).

Let's assume you have markup similar to the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="top">
      <div id="top-bg">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Despite the fact that `#top-bg` has `width: 100%` it will only ever be `900px` wide as it is a child of `#top` and width percentages are relative to the parent container's width.

Comment: ok so I take it to solve the problem I can just adjust the sizes of each parent container as the child will change automatically based on this.

Comment: @Wayne0881 Yes as long as the child has a percentage width, if at any point in it's ancestry there is a fixed width element, that will be the maximum width it can achieve.